# Two approaches to a numerical integration give different results. How to determine if this is a result of numerical conditioning?

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to do the following integration

$$\int_{ps_1}^{ps_2} \int_{pt_1}^{pt_2} \frac{e^{-k\,r(s,t)}}{r(s,t)}\, ds \, dt$$

Where $r(s,t)$ is the distance between points in two distinct line segment ($ps_1$ to $ps_2$ and $pt_1$ to $pt_2$), $k$ is a complex constant which $Re(k) < 0$.

I thought the easier way to go would be using a multiplying factor (to determine the point along the line) as integrand such that

$$u_s = 0 \to ps_1$$

and

$$u_s = 1 \to ps_2$$

The implemented integration being

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-k\,r(u_s,u_t)}}{r(u_s,u_t)}\, du_s \, du_t$$

A colleague of mine working on the same problem got different results from what I got. Comparing our implementations, I say they are mathematically identical...

Function definitions

```
integral[snd_, rcv_, k_] := Block[
   {ei, ef, ri, rf, Ls, Lr, int, r, pe, pr},
   ei = snd[[1]];
   ef = snd[[2]];
   ri = rcv[[1]];
   rf = rcv[[2]];
   Ls = Norm[ef - ei];
   Lr = Norm[rf - ri];
   int = NIntegrate[
     pe = (ef - ei) ts/Ls + ei;
     pr = (rf - ri) tr/Lr + ri;
     r = Norm[pe - pr];
     Exp[-k r]/r,
     {tr, 0., Lr}, {ts, 0., Ls},
     WorkingPrecision -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 200
     ];
   Return[int]
   ];

integral2[snd_, rcv_, k_] := Block[
   {ei, ef, ri, rf, Ls, Lr, int, r, pe, pr},
   ei = snd[[1]];
   ef = snd[[2]];
   ri = rcv[[1]];
   rf = rcv[[2]];
   Ls = Norm[ef - ei];
   Lr = Norm[rf - ri];
   int = NIntegrate[
     pe = (ef - ei) ts + ei;
     pr = (rf - ri) tr + ri;
     r = Norm[pe - pr];
     Exp[-k r]/r,
     {tr, 0., 1.}, {ts, 0., 1.},
     WorkingPrecision -> 10, MaxRecursion -> 200
     ];
   Return[int]
   ];
```

Testing

```
h = 0.3;
L = 1.0;
snd = {{0., 0., h}, {L, 0., h}};
rcv = {{0., L, -h}, {L, 0., -h}};
integral[snd, rcv, -1]
integral2[snd, rcv, -1]
```

Results in

```
3.949134609
2.792459862
```

Where is the mistake, is it implementation-wise or is the assumption I've made (mathematical identity) wrong? Or is this something related to numerical conditioning?

Any help is apprecciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the transformation formula for integrals, the second integral should read

```
Ls Lr NIntegrate[
  pe = (ef - ei) ts + ei;
  pr = (rf - ri) tr + ri;
  r = Norm[pe - pr];
  Exp[-k r]/r, 
  {tr, 0., 1.}, {ts, 0., 1.}]
```